# Problem solving complex equation with high power

Tags: complex-numbers

I have to solve :$$(i+z)^{16}-(7+7i)(i+z)^8+25i=0$$
I consider this equation like a quadratic equation and find its delta and solutions. But i can't solve two equations :$$(i+z)^8=4+3i$$
$$(i+z)^8=3+4i$$
I really need some helps to solve completely this equation. Thanks.

Comment: Convert the RHS to polar form, find the eighth root(s), and solve for $z$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use polar coordinates, the eighth roots can be found by repeated square root.

We get the square root
$$  (x+iy)^2 = a+ib $$
when
$$  x = \frac{1}{2} \left( \sqrt{ \sqrt{a^2+b^2} + b}  + \sqrt{\sqrt{a^2+b^2} - b} \right)  $$

$$  y = \frac{1}{2} \left( \sqrt{ \sqrt{a^2+b^2} + b}  - \sqrt{\sqrt{a^2+b^2} - b} \right)  $$

if the real parts $a,b$ are positive, so are the $x,y$ above are also positive. Switching $a,b$ to $b,a$ gives a different result.

Comment: Don't you think it could be easier to write $a+bi=\frac 1{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}(\cos(x)+i\sin(x))$ and identify $x$ ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici sure. Still, it all can be done with lots of square root signs applying to real quantities. If there is no interest from the OP, little is lost.